# Drop down lookup field search

Tags: search, lookup-column, dropdown

I've got the following scenario: List A contains several thousand items, List B has a lookup field to List A. When a user is creating item in List B she has to select the List A item via the mentioned lookup field. Additionally, when creating List B item user has to choose "Sector" value which could potentially limit the number of items in the drop down list.

The issue I am facing is the number of records the user has to go through to find the one she is interested in. I was trying to find any solution, but I did not find anything. Do you know if there is anything that I can do to help the user to find the relevant item? I was thinking about some kind of a search option or choosing the item from a webpart instead of a simple drop down list. If this is not possible, how can I implement the following mechanism: user chooses the "Sector" which acts as a filter for the lookup field?

Any help will be appreciated.

Lukasz

Answer (score 3):

I use [Chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Easy to implement, and I used this week with a lookup with more than 500 itens, works really fast and easy.

you will need:

```
jquery-1.12.1.min.js
chosen.jquery.js
chosen.css
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search seems to have found what you require:
http://jassimkhan.blogspot.ca/2010/10/implement-cascading-dropdown-in.html

This utilizes some custom javascript to handle the dependent drop-down functionality you are after.  It also requires you build an additional list to reference values from.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I will give it a go. However, I'd love to hear if there is a way to enable search functionality. Unfortunately, I don't have any power over the server so any server-side solution is beyond reach for me.