# How to use Chosen JQuery in Sharepoint

Tags: lookup-column, cewp

I know how to implement a Chosen field in an HTML file, but how can I set the code, so the Chosen.js is applying the behaviour in a Lookup field?

I found about Chosen.js here, but sadly found nowhere how to implement it in a SharePoint Lookup field:

> [Drop down lookup field search](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122974/drop-down-lookup-field-search/177383#177383)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to make a lookup field to be searchable using chosen.js

```
$(SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('LookupFieldInternalName').Controls).find('select').chosen({width: "100px"});
```

JS files required:

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/),[SPUtility](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility),[Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)