# How to embed a search field in a dropdown of a lookup column's cell

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, lookup-column, dropdown, cascading-dropdown

Let's say I have a list which is opened in quick edit mode(Datasheet view) have a lookup column when I click on any cell of the column I can see a drop down of items and also that drop down getting filtered based on the input/text that I type in the cell. The default search filter in the lookup column drop-down matches the characters entered with the starting characters of the items in the drop-down. Eg: If there is an item called "ABC DEF" in the drop-down list, this item will be shown in the filter only If I enter "AB" If I want to search by entering "DEF" it's not working.

So is there any way where I can change the custom search filter way of lookup column drop-down (or) Is there any way where we can embed a search field in the drop-down which filters out the drop-down of items based on the regular expression match that I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet view is configured by Access ActiveX component in SharePoint Online.

We are not able to change its default behavior.

Comment: Are you certain it's ActiveX (or even Access)? It was in 2010 but I thought it was removed in 2013/16/SPO.

Comment: Is there any way that we can do this to achieve a customized drop-down of lookup? I found this string online: [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122974/drop-down-lookup-field-search?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I don't know whether this thing is a workaround for this issue or not